# Powershell list.workflowassociation not working right

Tags: 2010, powershell

I encountered recently a weird problem.
I'm using a powershell script to :
- save all workflows autostart properties (from all lists/webs/sites)
- make modifications to items in the lists
- restore autostart properties

To do so, I get to the lists and then use $list.WorkflowAssociations to retrieve all workflows.
The thing is, sometimes, for a list with 3 workflow versions for example, the result contains 3 objects, but one of them is duplicated...
If I run the same command again, right after, I get the correct list.

After that, if I run iisreset, I can't reproduce the error before the next day.

What do you think of this problem ? is the .WorkflowAssociations not reliable ?

Thanks for your help